# React: Using Material UI Icons as a button?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newb to React and front-end development and I recently started playing with Material UI. Is there a way to hook an icon to an action?

I'm looking for something like this:

`<DeleteIcon onClick={this.handleClick} />`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap the DeleteIcon in an IconButton:

```
<IconButton onClick={this.handleClick}>
   <DeleteIcon/>
</IconButton>
```

Look here for more details: https://material-ui.com/api/icon-button/